# php regex matching issue

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this kind of output:
1342&-4&-6
And it could be more times or less:
1342&-4  (I need to replace it with: 1342,1344)
1340&-1&-3&-5&-7 (I need to replace it with: 1340,1341,1343,1345,1347)

I've tried to use preg_match but with no success, 
Can someone help me with that?

Thanks,

Comment: the replacement rules are not clear (to me at least)

Comment: 1342&-4&-6   -->  1342 and 1344 and 1346

Comment: 1340&-1&-3&-5&-7 -->   1340 and 1341 and 1343 and 1345 and 1347

Comment: 1342&-4    --> 1342 and 1344

Comment: so if you had sting input of "1342&-4" you would get 2 stings returned "1342" and "1344"?

Comment: yes and if the output is 1340&-1&-3&-5&-7 i need to get "1340" "1341" "1343" "1345" "1347"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php



//so if you had sting input of "1342&-4" you would get 2 stings returned "1342" and "1344"? 

//1340&-1&-3&-5&-7 --> 1340 and 1341 and 1343 and 1345 and 1347

//$str="1342&-4";
$str="1340&-1&-3&-5&-7";
$x=explode('&-',$str);

//print_r($x);

foreach ($x as $k=> $v){
    if($k==0){
        //echo raw
        echo $v."<br>";
    }else{
    //remove last number add new last number 
    echo substr($x[0], 0, -1).$v."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

output:

1340
1341
1343
1345
1347

i used `<br>` you can use what ever you need or add to a new variable(array)

Comment: Thanks guys, both of your answers are good but Dagon's suggestion was more compatible to my code so I'm going to use it. thanks a lot

Comment: @K.D dont forget to accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Dagon, sorry about off-topic but, what obsession do you have with "potatoes"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode('&-', $string);

$len = count($array);

for($i=1; $i<$len; $i++)

    $array[$i] += $array[0]  / 10 * 10;

var_dump(implode(' ', $array));
```

Comment: It works - but a one-liner explanation to go with your code would be useful.